# What is the exception datatype?

Tags: c++

I was reading my C++ text and it showed me this error scaffolding. However it doesn't explain the "exception& e" part.I know that the & means something is being "passed by reference", but I've never seen the exception datatype.

```
#include "std_lib_facililies.h"
int main(){
    try {
    //your code here
    keep_window_open();
    return 0 ;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: n << e. whatO << '\n ' ;
    keep_window_openO:
    return 1 ;
    }
    catch (...) {
    cerr « "Oops: unknown exception!\n";
    keep_window_open() ;
    return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Standard Library defines it as the parent type for exceptions thrown by the Standard Library: [std::exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/

Comment: This code is weird, it looks like OCR